# How to use azuread_claims_mapping_policy?

Tags: azure-active-directory, terraform-provider-azure

I'm trying to provision `azuread_claims_mapping_policy` but it fails due to missing permissions.

```
│ Error: retrieving Claims Mapping Policy with object ID: "<GUID HERE>"
│ 
│   with azuread_claims_mapping_policy.integration_claims_mapping[0],
│   on active_directory.tf line 54, in resource "azuread_claims_mapping_policy" "integration_claims_mapping":
│   54: resource "azuread_claims_mapping_policy" "integration_claims_mapping" {
│ 
│ ClaimsMappingPolicyClient.BaseClient.Get(): unexpected status 403 with
│ OData error: Authorization_RequestDenied: Insufficient privileges to
│ complete the operation.
```

The code is executed in context of Managed Identity

As it is written here in [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/resources/claims_mapping_policy):

> When authenticated with a service principal, this resource requires the following application roles: Policy.ReadWrite.ApplicationConfiguration and Policy.Read.All
>
> When authenticated with a user principal, this resource requires one of the following directory roles: Application Administrator or Global Administrator

I added `Application Administrator` role to that identity. But it failed with te result above. It passes with `Global Administrator`, but I would prefer to avoid this.

Is there a way to provision `azuread_claims_mapping_policy` without `Global Administrator` role?

Here is the code I used:

```
locals {
  entity_ids = {
    "dev" : ["entity-id"],
  }

  redirect_uris = {
    "dev" : ["redirect-uri"],
  }
}

data "azuread_client_config" "current" {}

resource "azuread_application" "saml_integration" {
  count           = var.env == "prod" ? 0 : 1
  display_name    = "SAML integration - ${upper(var.env)}"
  owners          = [data.azuread_client_config.current.object_id]
  identifier_uris = local.entity_ids[var.env]

  web {
    redirect_uris = local.redirect_uris[var.env]
  }

  feature_tags {
    enterprise            = true
    gallery               = false
    custom_single_sign_on = true
  }

  app_role {
    allowed_member_types = ["Application", "User"]
    description          = "Default role for standard users used for SAML integration"
    display_name         = "IntegrationUser"
    enabled              = true
    id                   = "GUID HERE"
    value                = "IntegrationUser"
  }
}

resource "azuread_service_principal" "saml_integration_service_principal" {
  count                        = var.env == "prod" ? 0 : 1
  application_id               = azuread_application.saml_integration[0].application_id
  app_role_assignment_required = false
  owners                       = [data.azuread_client_config.current.object_id]

  use_existing                  = true
  preferred_single_sign_on_mode = "saml"

  feature_tags {
    enterprise            = true
    gallery               = false
    custom_single_sign_on = true
  }
}

resource "azuread_service_principal_token_signing_certificate" "signing_certificate" {
  service_principal_id = azuread_service_principal.saml_integration_service_principal[0].id
}

resource "azuread_service_principal_claims_mapping_policy_assignment" "app" {
  count                    = var.env == "prod" ? 0 : 1
  claims_mapping_policy_id = azuread_claims_mapping_policy.integration_claims_mapping[0].id
  service_principal_id     = azuread_service_principal.saml_integration_service_principal[0].id
}

resource "azuread_claims_mapping_policy" "integration_claims_mapping" {
  count        = var.env == "prod" ? 0 : 1
  display_name = "Claims Mapping for ${azuread_application.saml_integration[0].display_name}"
  definition = [
    jsonencode(
      {
        ... hidden
    )
  ]
}

resource "azuread_user" "test_user" {
  count               = var.env == "prod" ? 0 : 1
  user_principal_name = "test-saml-user-${var.env}@contoso.com"
  mail                = "test-saml-user-${var.env}@contoso.com"
  display_name        = "Test Contoso SSO User ${var.env}"
  given_name = "Test"
  surname = "User ${upper(var.env)}"
  password            = "SUBERPASSWORD"
}

resource "azuread_group" "test_app_users_group" {
  count            = var.env == "prod" ? 0 : 1
  display_name     = "Test SAML integration - ${upper(var.env)}"
  owners           = [data.azuread_client_config.current.object_id]
  security_enabled = true
  members = [
    azuread_user.test_user[0].object_id
  ]
}

resource "azuread_app_role_assignment" "test_user_group_assignment" {
  app_role_id         = azuread_service_principal.saml_integration_service_principal[0].app_role_ids["IntegrationUser"]
  principal_object_id = azuread_group.test_app_users_group[0].object_id
  resource_object_id  = azuread_service_principal.saml_integration_service_principal[0].object_id
}
```

Please note that some values are hidden to do not expose confidential data.

Comment: Hi @Krzysztof Madej, Kindly share the terraform code, what you have tried?

Comment: I added, but I doubt if it brings value here.

Comment: I [created](https://i.imgur.com/QcbNgVU.png) a mapping policy using Terraform with the **Application Administrator** role only. Here is my [result](https://i.imgur.com/hLB8lWH.png). Try to execute only mapping claim policy code from your end to create mapping policy.

Comment: Did you use Managed Identity to authenticate? It looks that Managed Identity is type of Service Principal and as this it should get `Policy.ReadWrite.ApplicationConfiguration and Policy.Read.All` permissions. But why it works with Global Administrator then?

Comment: Hi @Krzysztof Madej,  I created a mapping policy using Terraform with a Service Principal that has the [API permission](https://i.imgur.com/3hiePFz.png). Here is [my result](https://i.imgur.com/veZ7SSp.png). However, I'm also encountering the same [error](https://i.imgur.com/3QNjDBJ.png) as you when I remove the `Policy.Read.All` permission. You can refer to the same issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azuread/issues/804).Just for your information, I'm using version **azuread v2.44.0** and **azurerm v3.77.0**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had add following permissions:

- `Application.ReadWrite.All`
- `Policy.ReadWrite.ApplicationConfiguration`
- `Policy.Read.All`

But since there is no possibility to do this via Portal (for managed identities) I used script from [this article](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-integration-services-blog/grant-graph-api-permission-to-managed-identity-object/ba-p/2792127).

```
$TenantID = "provide the tenant ID"
$GraphAppId = "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000"
$DisplayNameOfMSI = "Provide the Logic App name"
$PermissionNames = @("Application.ReadWrite.All", "Policy.ReadWrite.ApplicationConfiguration", "Policy.Read.All") 

# Install the module
Install-Module AzureAD

Connect-AzureAD -TenantId $TenantID

$MSI = (Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "displayName eq '$DisplayNameOfMSI'")
Start-Sleep -Seconds 10

$GraphServicePrincipal = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "appId eq '$GraphAppId'"

foreach ($PermissionName in $PermissionNames) {
    $AppRole = $GraphServicePrincipal.AppRoles | Where-Object { $_.Value -eq $PermissionName -and $_.AllowedMemberTypes -contains "Application" }
    New-AzureAdServiceAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $MSI.ObjectId -PrincipalId $MSI.ObjectId -ResourceId $GraphServicePrincipal.ObjectId -Id $AppRole.Id
}

Write-Output "Permissions added successfully."
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Error: retrieving Claims Mapping Policy with object ID

The below error is encoutered ,If the service principal does not have **Policy.ReadWrite.ApplicationConfiguration** and **Policy.Read.All** permissions and has also not been granted consent.

When I try to create a `mapping policy`  using `Service Principal`  with the `API` permissions listed below, I encounter the same error.

**Policy.ReadWrite.ApplicationConfiguration**
**Application.ReadWrite.All**

[image]

I created a mapping policy using `Terraform` with a `Service Principal` that has below `API` permission.

[image]

Fyi I'm using latest version of `azuread v2.44.0` and `azurerm v3.77.0`

**Terraform Code:**

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

terraform {
  required_providers {
    azuread = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azuread"
    }
  }
}

provider "azuread" {
  tenant_id = "xnnxcncnfnf"
  use_cli  = false 
  client_id     = "gjgjhlhlmamdhdmd"
  client_secret = "ghgjhkhlhmdmdhsgf"
}

resource "azuread_claims_mapping_policy" "my_policy" {
  definition = [
    jsonencode(
      {
        ClaimsMappingPolicy = {
          ClaimsSchema = [
            {
              ID            = "employeeid"
              JwtClaimType  = "name"
              SamlClaimType = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name"
              Source        = "user"
            },
            {
              ID            = "tenantcountry"
              JwtClaimType  = "country"
              SamlClaimType = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/country"
              Source        = "company"
            }
          ]
          IncludeBasicClaimSet = "true"
          Version              = 1
        }
      }
    ),
  ]
  display_name = "sample-venkat-policy1"
}
```

**Terraform Output:**

[image]

You can refer to the same issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azuread/issues/804).

Comment: It was a bit more complicated to add permissions to Managed Identity, but I found [this article](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-integration-services-blog/grant-graph-api-permission-to-managed-identity-object/ba-p/2792127).  But even then I got error with not enough permissions.

Comment: Thanks you for this link. It helped me to find missing permission.